# How can i parse a JSON file with other language(i.e Gujrati in this case) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am sharing my json file as well as code below.Thanks in advance.How can i parse the data into a listview?I want to add it to list tile with which i can show image,description and title. I am trying to make an news app where i want to display these three things mentioned above.

This is my JSON file..

```
[ {"283577" : {"title" : "`10 દિ''માં પાક થશે ધૂળ ચાટતું ''","image" : "","description" : "પ્રમોદ મુઝુમદાર તરફથી-
    નવી દિલ્હી, તા. 28 : અહીં વડાપ્રધાન નરેન્દ્ર મોદીએ એનસીસી કેડેટ્સને સંબોધન કરતાં પાકિસ્તાનનું નામ લીધા વિના જ તેને કડક શબ્દમાં ચેતવણી આપી હતી. પીએમ મોદીએ કહ્યું કે પાડોશી દેશ જાણે છે કે તેને ભારતથી ત્રણ-ત્રણ યુદ્ધમાં પરાજય મળ્યો છે. ભારતીય સેના ઈચ્છે તો તેને અઠવાડિયા-10 દિવસમાં હરાવીને ધૂળ ચટાવી શકે છે.' તેમણે સીએએ મામલે કોંગ્રેસ, બસપ સહિત વિપક્ષો પર પણ નિશાન સાધ્યું હતું. પીએમે કહ્યું કે પહેલાંની સરકારોએ દશકાઓ સુધી સંસદમાં નાગરિકતા સંશોધન બિલ, એનિમી પ્રોપર્ટી બિલ લટકાવી રાખ્યા હતા અને માત્ર પોતાની મતબેન્કની રાજનીતિ કરતા રહ્યા હતા. અહીં નેશનલ કેડેટ કોરની વાર્ષિક રેલીમાં પીએમે પાકિસ્તાનનું નામ લીધા વિના કહ્યું કે આપણી સેનાને તેને ધૂળ ચાટતું કરવામાં માત્ર 10-12 દિવસનો સમય લાગશે. હવે તે દશકાઓથી ભારત સામે પ્રોક્સી યુદ્ધ કરી રહ્યુ છે. તેમાં અનેક નાગરિકનાં મોત થયાં છે. આપણા જવાનો શહીદ થઈ રહ્યા છે. સીએએ-એનઆરસી પર પીએમ મોદીએ કહ્યું હતું કે અફવાઓ ફેલાવનારાઓ એટલું સમજી લે કે મોદી પોતાની પ્રતિષ્ઠા માટે પેદા થયો નથી. મોદી માટે તો તેના દેશની પ્રતિષ્ઠા જ સર્વસ્વ છે. દશકાઓ જૂની સમસ્યાઓને ઉકેલી રહેલી અમારી સરકારના નિર્ણયો પર જે કેટલાક લોકો સાંપ્રદાયિકતાનો રંગ ચડાવી રહ્યા છે તેમના અસલી ચહેરા પણ દેશે જોઈ લીધા છે. હું ફરી કહી રહ્યો છું, દેશ જોઈ રહ્યો છે, સમજી રહ્યો છે. ચૂપ છે પરંતુ બધું સમજી રહ્યો છે. આ પછી તેમણે કોંગ્રેસને નિશાને લેતાં કહ્યું હતું કે પહેલાંની સરકારો એવું માનતી' રહી કે આતંકવાદ, બોમ્બ ધડાકા આ બધું કાનૂન વ્યવસ્થાની પરેશાની છે. ભારત માતા લોહીલુહાણ થતી ગઈ.. વાતો બહુ થઈ, ભાષણો બહુ થયાં પરંતુ જયારે આપણી સેના પગલાં ભરવા માટે કહેતી ત્યારે ના પાડી દેવામાં આવતી હતી. પીએમ મોદીએ કહ્યું કે આજે યુવાવિચાર, યુવા મન સાથે દેશ આગળ વધી રહ્યો છે. એટલે જ તે સર્જિકલ સ્ટ્રાઈક કરે છે, એરસ્ટ્રાઈક કરે છે અને આતંકના આકાઓને તેમના ઘરમાં જઈને પાઠ ભણાવે છે. પીએમે જણાવ્યું હતું કે, જે લોકો સીએએનો ડર ફેલાવી રહ્યા છે તેઓ પાકિસ્તાનમાં લઘુમતીઓના ઉત્પીડનને જોવાનો ઇનકાર કરી રહ્યા છે. શું આપણે દમનનો ભોગ બનેલા લોકોની મદદ ન કરવી જોઈએ એવો સવાલ વડાપ્રધાને કર્યો હતો. તેમણે જણાવ્યું હતું કે, અમારી સરકાર ઐતિહાસિક ભૂલને સુધારવા અને પાડોશી દેશોના લઘુમતીઓને આપેલું વચન પૂરું કરવા સીએએ લઈ આવી છે. મોદીએ અગાઉ કાશ્મીર મુદ્દે વિપક્ષ પર નિશાન સાધતાં જણાવ્યું હતું કે અગાઉ કાશ્મીરની સમસ્યાના સમાધાન માટે શું કરવામાં આવ્યું હતું? ત્રણ-ચાર પરિવારોએ આ સમસ્યા સુલઝાવવાને બદલે તેને ઉલઝાવી નાખી હતી.વડા પ્રધાને રૅલીને સંબોધતાં જણાવ્યું હતું કે, એનસીસી યુવાનોમાં અનુશાસન દૃઢસંકલ્પ અને નિષ્ઠાની ભાવના ઊભી કરવાનું સશક્ત મંચ છે. તે દેશના વિકાસ સાથે સીધેસીધું જોડાયેલું છે.આ પ્રસંગે એનસીસીની રેલીમાં સંરક્ષણપ્રધાન રાજનાથ સિંહ, શ્રીપાદ પસોં નાઇક, ચીફ અૉફ ડિફેન્સ સ્ટાફ (સીડીએસ) બિપિન રાવત અને ભારતીય લશ્કરની ત્રણ પાંખોના વડા તેમ જ વરિષ્ઠ લશ્કરી અધિકારીઓ હાજર રહ્યા હતા.'"} ,"283574" : {"title" : "દેશદ્રોહનો આરોપી શરજીલ ગિરફ્તાર","image" : "","description" : "પટણા તા. 28 : સીએએ વિરોધી ચળવળકાર અને જેએનયુના છાત્ર શરજીલ ઈમામની દિલ્હી પોલીસે રાજદ્રોહના કેસમાં બિહારના જેહાનાબાદમાંથી ધરપકડ કરી હતી. આ નવા કાયદા સામેના વિરોધ દરમિયાનના, આસામને ભારતથી અળગું કરવા સહિતના કથિત ભડકાઉ ભાષણો કરવા સબબ કેટલાક રાજ્યોમાં ઈમામ સામે રાજદ્રોહના કેસ નોંધાયા છે. શાહીન બાગમાંના વિરોધોના શરૂના આયોજક રહેલા ઈમામને તા. 3 ફેબ્રુઆરીએ પ્રોકટોરીઅલ કમિટી સમક્ષ હાજર થવા જણાવાયું હતું. પોલીસ તેના ભાઈને અગાઉ ઝડપી ચૂકી છે. તેની સામે આઈપીસીની કલમ 124-એ, 1પ3-એ અને પ0પ હેઠળ કેસ નોંધાયો છે. દિલ્હી પોલીસને ઈમામના ટ્રાન્ઝિટ રિમાન્ડ મળ્યા હતા અને તેને દિલ્હી લાવવામાં આવશે. દિલ્હી પોલીસે એક પત્રકાર પરિષદ કરીને જણાવ્યું હતું કે, શરજીલે શરણાગતિ સ્વીકારી નથી તેની ધરપકડ જ કરાઈ છે. બિહાર, આસામ, અરુણાચલ પ્રદેશ, યુપી, દિલ્હી અને મણિપુર-આ છ રાજ્યોની પોલીસે તેની સામે આઈપીસીની સંબંધિત કલમો' હેઠળ' કેસ' નોંધ્યા છે. ગઈકાલે કેન્દ્રની તપાસનીશ એજન્સીએ બિહારના જેહાનાબાદમાં ઈમામના વંશજોના ઘરે છાપો મારી તેના નાના ભાઈને ઝડપી લીધો હતો. ઈમામના ભાષણનો વીડિયો ભાજપે 2પમીએ જારી કર્યો હતો અને તેમાં તે એક નાના ટોળાને એમ કહેતો સાંભળવા મળી રહ્યો છે કે `મુસ્લિમોએ સંગઠિત થવું રહ્યું અને આસામને ભારતથી અળગું' પાડવું રહ્યંy.''"} ,"283573" : {"title" : "બેન્ક હડતાળ મુદ્દે હાઈકોર્ટની નોટિસ","image" : "","description" : "અમદાવાદ, તા. 28 (અમારા પ્રતિનિધિ દ્વારા) : રાષ્ટ્રીયકૃત્ત બેન્કોના 10 યુનિયનોએ 31 જાન્યુઆરી અને પહેલી ફેબ્રુઆરીએ આપેલા હડતાળના એલાનને પગલે ગુજરાત ટ્રેડર્સ ફેડરેશન સહિત અનેક સંગઠનો દ્વારા હાઇકાર્ટમાં કરેલી જાહેર હિતની અરજી અદાલતે મંજૂર રાખી છે અને આ કેસમાં રિઝર્વ બેન્ક ઓફ ઇન્ડિયા (આરબીઆઇ), નાણાં મંત્રાલય, ભારત સરકાર, ઇન્ડિયન બેન્ક એસોસિયેશન અને બેન્ક એમ્પ્લોયીઝ એસોસિયેશનને નોટીસ ફટકારી છે. વેપાર અને ઉદ્યોગની મૂળભૂત સમસ્યા પર ધ્યાન કેન્દ્રિત કરવા માટે ન્યાયતંત્ર દ્વારા લેવામાં આવેલ આ એક મોટુ પગલું છે. ગુજરાત ટ્રેડર્સ ફેડરેશન, રાજકોટ ચેમ્બર ઓફ કોમર્સ એન્ડ ઇન્ડસ્ટ્રી, મધ્ય ગુજરાત ચેમ્બર ઓફ કોમર્સ એન્ડ ઇન્ડસ્ટ્રી, ભાવનગર ડિસ્ટ્રીક્ટ ચેમ્બર ઓફ કોમર્સ એન્ડ ઇન્ડસ્ટ્રી, ગોન્ડલ ચેમ્બર ઓફ કોમર્સ અને ઇન્ડ, જામનગર વેપારી મહા મંડળ, સોરઠ ચેમ્બર, અમદાવાદ ઓટો ડીલર્સ એસોસિયેશન વતી ગુજરાત હાઇકોર્ટમાં વરિષ્ઠ વકીલ રશ્મીન જાની હાજર રહ્યા હતા.' '"} ,"283571" : {"title" : "ચીનમાં ફસાયેલા છાત્રોને એરલિફ્ટ કરવા તૈયારી","image" : "","description" : "નવી દિલ્હી/વડોદરા, તા.28 : કોરોના વાયરસને પગલે ચીનના કેટલાક શહેરો `બંધ' કરી દેવાયા છે અને મોટા પાયે ભારતીયો પણ ફસાયા છે, ત્યારે રાજપીપળા ખાતે વિવિધ કાર્યક્રમોમાં હાજરી આપવા જઇ રહેલા વિદેશ મંત્રી જયશંકરે હરણી એરપોર્ટ ખાતે પત્રકારો સાથેની વાતચીતમાં જણાવ્યું હતું કે, ચીનમાં ફસાયેલા દેશના તમામ વિદ્યાર્થીને સુરક્ષિત પરત લાવવા માટે સરકાર તમામ શક્ય પ્રયાસો કરી રહી છે. મંજૂરી મળતાં જ ખાનગી પ્લેનમાં વિદ્યાર્થીઓને લાવવામાં આવશે. વિદેશ મંત્રાલયના પ્રવકતા રવીશકુમારે જણાવ્યુ હતું કે બીજિંગમાંનો ભારતીય દૂતાવાસ આ બાબતે ચીની સરકાર, સત્તાવાળાઓ અને આપણા નાગરિકોના સંપર્કમાં રહે છે અને તે વિશેની અપડેટ સહભાગી કરતા રહેશું. વુહાનમાં ફસાયેલા 8 ભારતીય વિદ્યાર્થીઓએ ભારત સરકારને તાત્કાલિક બચાવ કામગીરી હાથ ધરવા અપીલ કરી છે અને કહ્યું છે કે, શહેર સંપૂર્ણપણે બંધ કરાયું છે અને હવે તો ખાવા પીવાની ય તકલીફ છે.બીજિંગમાંના ભારતીય દૂતાવાસે હુબેઈમાંના વિદ્યાર્થીઓને મોકલેલા સંદેશમાં જણાવ્યુ છે કે તેઓને ખાલી કરાવવા માટેની તારીખ અને તરીકા (લોજિસ્ટિકસ) ઘડી કાઢવા ચીની સરકાર અને સત્તાવાળા સાથે સંપર્કમાં છીએ. ખાલી કરવાના તારીખ અને તરીકા ઉચિત સમયે જણાવાશે. જેઓ પાસે આવા વિકલ્પો ઉપલબ્ધ છે તેઓને ભારતમાં આવી પહોંચવા સાથે ફરજિયાત 14 દિવસ કવોરેન્ટાઈનમાં રહેવાનું રહેશે.' વિદેશ મંત્રીએ વધુમાં જણાવ્યું હતું કે, ચીનમાં ફસાયેલા ભારતીય તમામ છાત્ર સુરક્ષિત છે. તેમને સહીસલામત વહેલી તકે ભારત લાવવા માટે સરકાર દ્વારા પ્રાઇવેટ પ્લેન પણ તૈયાર રાખવામાં આવ્યું છે. ચીનથી વિદ્યાર્થીઓને લાવવા માટે તૈયાર રાખવામાં આવેલ પ્રાઇવેટ પ્લેન ચીન મોકલવા માટે ચીન સરકાર પાસે મંજૂરી માંગવામાં આવી છે. મંજૂરી મળતા જ પ્લેન ચીન રવાના કરવામાં આવશે. અને ફસાયેલા સ્ટુડન્ટ્સને સહી સલામત ભારત લાવવામાં આવશે. થોડો સમય લાગશે. પરંતુ, તમામ સ્ટુડન્ટસને સહી સલામત લાવવામાં આવશે. ભારતમાં કોરોનાની કોઇ અસર નથી. પરંતુ, તંત્ર એલર્ટ છે. ચીનથી પરત ફરતા લોકોને ક્રેનીંગ કરાવી લેવા માટે સરકાર તરફથી પરિપત્ર જારી કરાયો છે.'"} ,"283569" : {"title" : "અમદાવાદમાં બિલ્ડરો પર આયકર દરોડા","image" : "","description" : "અમદાવાદ, તા. 28 : અમદાવાદના ઇન્કમટેક્સ વિભાગે આજે વહેલી સવારથી રીઅલ એસ્ટેટ બિઝનેસ સાથે સંકળાયેલા બે બિલ્ડર ગ્રુપ પર સપાટો બોલાવ્યો છે. થલતેજ-શીલજના જાણીતા બિલ્ડર અજય શ્રીધર અને મારુતિ ગ્રુપ સહિત એચઓએફ (હાઉસ ઓફ ફર્નિચર) ફર્નિચરના શો-રૂમ પર ગાંધીનગર ટીમ દ્વારા મેગા સર્ચ ઓપરેશન હાથ ધરવામાં આવ્યું છે. આ ઘટનાના પગલે બિલ્ડર લોબીમાં ફફડાટ જોવા મળી' રહ્યો છે. આજે વહેલી સવારથી આવકવેરા વિભાગના 50થી વધુ અધિકારી દ્વારા સર્વેની કામગીરી હાથ ધરાઇ છે. શ્રીધર ગ્રુપની મિલકત સહિત જમીનના દસ્તાવેજો, રોકડ અને અન્ય મિલકતોની તપાસ અજય શ્રીધર અને તેમના પરિવારની હાજરીમાં તેમના નિવાસસ્થાને થઇ રહી છે. આ ગ્રુપ દ્વારા બનાવવામાં આવેલી શાળા પર પણ આવકવેરા વિભાગે તપાસ હાથ ધરી હોવાનું જાણવા મળે' છે. થલતેજ અને શીલજમાં શ્રીધર ગ્રુપની અનેક સ્કીમ છે. અંદાજે ત્રણ ગ્રુપમાં ચાલી રહેલા સર્ચ ઓપરેશનમાં 24 ટીમ જોડાઇ છે.અજય શ્રીધર અમદાવાદના ખ્યાતનામ બિલ્ડર છે. તેમના નિવાસસ્થાન થલતેજ અને ઓફિસ શીલજમાં છે અને ફ્લેટ-ઓફિસ ઇટાલિયન ડિઝાઇનના લીધે થલતેજમાં આવેલો તેમનો બંગલો વ્હાઇટ બંગલો તરીકે ઓળખાય છે. દરોડાની કાર્યવાહી દરમિયાન અનેક મોટા પ્રમાણમાં બેનામી વ્યવહારો અને કરોડોનું કાળું નાણું મળી આવવાની શક્યતા છે. હાલમાં તમામ સ્થળે સર્ચની કામગીરી ચાલુ છે, જે આવતીકાલ સુધી લંબાઇ શકે છે.'રાંચરડા પાસે કરોડોની જમીનનો સોદો' થયો હોવાની વિગતો મળતા ઇન્કમટેક્સ અધિકારી ઓ દ્વારા ખાનગી રાહે તપાસ શરૂ કરવામાં આવી હતી અને તેમાં મહત્ત્વપૂર્ણ વિગતો જાણવા મળી હતી જેના આધારે આજે સવારથી જ ઇન્કમટેક્સ વિભાગના અધિકારીઓની આગેવાનીમાં 24 સ્થળો પર અમદાવાદ શહેરમાં સામૂહિક રીતે બિલ્ડર અજય શ્રીધર, રાજુભાઇ પટેલ તથા દિનેશ જૈન તથા જમીનનો લે-વેચનો ધંધો કરતા બિલ્ડર શરદ પટેલને ત્યાં દરોડો પાડતાં વેપારીઓમાં ફફડાટ ફેલાયો છે.''"} } ]
```

And  this is my code

```java
    import 'dart:collection';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

    void main() => runApp(ParseJson());

    class ParseJson extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ParseJson createState() => new _ParseJson();
    }

    class _ParseJson extends State<ParseJson> {
      Map data;
      List newsData;

      Future<List<News>> fetchPosts() async {
        http.Response response = await http
            .get('https://www.example.com/json');

        setState(() {
          newsData = data["283478"];
        });
        debugPrint(response.body);
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        fetchPosts();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold
          (body: Container(
          child: ListView(

          ),
        )));
      }
    }

    class News {
      final int id;
      final String title;
      final String image;
      final String description;

      News(this.id, this.title, this.image, this.description);
    }
```

Comment: pls ignore the number in setState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the example below that i have made from your given data.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<News> dataList = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  BuildContext context1;

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  Future loadyourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

// this is the local json that i have loaded from the assets folder
// you can make the http call here and else everything later is the same.

    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    // loading the json from the asset the above line
    String newStr = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length - 1);
    // removing the "[ ]" from the json where we can interpreat it as a map
    // you can use it your way for if removing and or using the list, but at last taking it into the list of object

    print(newStr);
    Map newStringMap = json.decode(newStr);
    var list = new List();
    newStringMap.forEach((key, value) {
      list.add(value);
    });

    for (var newsList in list) {
      var news = News.fromJson(newsList);
      dataList.add(news);
    }
    print('This is the length' + dataList.length.toString());
    print(dataList[0].title);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadyourData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dataList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Title :' + dataList[index].title),
                        Text('Description:' + dataList[index].description),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This is the main file where you show the data and make an api call.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final news = newsFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

News newsFromJson(String str) => News.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String newsToJson(News data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class News {
    String title;
    String image;
    String description;

    News({
        this.title,
        this.image,
        this.description,
    });

    factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => News(
        title: json["title"],
        image: json["image"],
        description: json["description"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "image": image,
        "description": description,
    };
}
```

This is the model class that i have made based on the json data you provided.

```
[ 
    { 
       "284221":{ 
          "title":"જોકોવિચ આઠમીવાર ઓસી ઓપન ચેમ્પિયન",
          "image":"",
          "description":"મેલબોર્ન, તા. 2 : સર્બિયાનો નોવાક જોકોવિચ ફાઇનલમાં પાંચ સેટની રસાકસી બાદ ઓસ્ટ્રિયાના જાયન્ટ કિલર બનીને ઉભરી આવેલા ડોમેનિક થીમને હાર આપીને રેકોર્ડ આઠમી વાર ઓસ્ટ્રલિયન ઓપન ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ટેનિસ ટૂર્નામેન્ટમાં ચેમ્પિયન બન્યો છે. આ વિજય સાથે જ જોકોવિચ ફરી એકવાર વિશ્વનો નંબર વન ખેલાડી બની ગયો છે. આજે રમાયેલી ફાઇનલમાં એક સમયે જોકોવિચ 1-2 સેટથી થીમની પાછળ હતો. આ પછી તેણે સતત બે સેટ જીતીને ઓસ્ટ્રેલિયન ઓપનનો તેનો ખિતાબ જાળવી રાખ્યો હતો. લગભગ ચાર કલાક સુધી ચાલેલી ફાઇનલમાં પાંચ સેટની રસાકસી બાદ થીમ સામે જોકોવિચનો 6-4, 4-6, 2-6, 6-3 અને 6-4થી વિજય થયો હતો. જોકોવિચનો આ 17મો ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબ છે. સર્વાધિક ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબના મામલે તે હવે રાફેલ નાદાલ (19)થી બે અને મહાન રોઝર ફેડરર (20)થી 3 ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબ પાછળ છે.'"
       },
       "284222":{ 
        "title":"જોકોવિચ આઠમીવાર ઓસી ઓપન ચેમ્પિયન",
        "image":"",
        "description":"મેલબોર્ન, તા. 2 : સર્બિયાનો નોવાક જોકોવિચ ફાઇનલમાં પાંચ સેટની રસાકસી બાદ ઓસ્ટ્રિયાના જાયન્ટ કિલર બનીને ઉભરી આવેલા ડોમેનિક થીમને હાર આપીને રેકોર્ડ આઠમી વાર ઓસ્ટ્રલિયન ઓપન ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ટેનિસ ટૂર્નામેન્ટમાં ચેમ્પિયન બન્યો છે. આ વિજય સાથે જ જોકોવિચ ફરી એકવાર વિશ્વનો નંબર વન ખેલાડી બની ગયો છે. આજે રમાયેલી ફાઇનલમાં એક સમયે જોકોવિચ 1-2 સેટથી થીમની પાછળ હતો. આ પછી તેણે સતત બે સેટ જીતીને ઓસ્ટ્રેલિયન ઓપનનો તેનો ખિતાબ જાળવી રાખ્યો હતો. લગભગ ચાર કલાક સુધી ચાલેલી ફાઇનલમાં પાંચ સેટની રસાકસી બાદ થીમ સામે જોકોવિચનો 6-4, 4-6, 2-6, 6-3 અને 6-4થી વિજય થયો હતો. જોકોવિચનો આ 17મો ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબ છે. સર્વાધિક ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબના મામલે તે હવે રાફેલ નાદાલ (19)થી બે અને મહાન રોઝર ફેડરર (20)થી 3 ગ્રાન્ડ સ્લેમ ખિતાબ પાછળ છે.'"
     }
    }
 ]
```

And this is the model class you provided.
I have taken you json locally and the parsed the data accordingly, you can make an api call, then after you just pass the String to the below method

Later every thing is the same.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much @sagaracharya. It worked but i want to parse the data in gujrati font iteself which is not happening.Thanks alot.

Comment: That's wired, the above json that you provided is in which language(I don't know its gujrati), but i can see the that same in my List.

Comment: I have uploaded my full json data..as it is for the news app, the data changes every day..how is it possible to parse this type of data?

Comment: data means are you saying  the keys are also changing, so the one you updated above "283577" is different from the key you mentioned previously.

Comment: Even i am trying.pls let me know.. Thanks alot.

Comment: check out the code I have made changes and let me know if it works

Comment: If its working then thats nice.Just add a check mark and give a upvote, so that it will be helpful for others

Comment: Thanks and  happy coding

Comment: hey @Chinmaay was my answer wrong , i would like to know why my green check was removed.

Comment: No your answer was right.I dont know why it happened..But i have accepted the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var response = await http.get('$url',
        headers: {"charset": "utf-8", "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"});
String utfDecode = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
```